# Composer error updating symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I can't update symfony from 2.3 to 3.x

Reading forums I have modified composer.json setting "minimum-stability": "dev" but I am receiving dependencies error. Really I don't know what means several packages because I think I'm using only php, symfony y doctrine
See my composer.json below:

```
   "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": ">3.0",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": ">1.6",
    "twig/extensions": ">1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": ">2.8",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": ">2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": ">2.3",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": ">2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": ">2.3",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": ">2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": ">2.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Dependencies error

> root@symfony2:/var/www/html/Symfony# composer update symfony/symfony
>   Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages. Problem 1
>       - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-bundle (locked at v1.2.0, required as >1.6) is satisfiable by
>   doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0] but these conflict with your
>   requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 2
>       - The requested package twig/extensions (locked at v1.0.0, required as >1.0) is satisfiable by twig/extensions[v1.0.0] but these
>   conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 3
>       - The requested package symfony/assetic-bundle (locked at v2.3.0, required as >2.8) is satisfiable by symfony/assetic-bundle[v2.3.0] but
>   these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem
>   4
>       - The requested package symfony/monolog-bundle (locked at v2.3.0, required as >2.3) is satisfiable by symfony/monolog-bundle[v2.3.0] but
>   these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem
>   5
>       - The requested package incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (locked at v2.0.0, required as >2.0) is satisfiable by
>   incenteev/composer-parameter-handler[v2.0.0] but these conflict with
>   your requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 6
>       - symfony/symfony dev-master requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - symfony/symfony 4.0.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 3.4.x-dev
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 3.3.x-dev

I have no experience using symfony, I have thought that I could install in a virtual machine the same packages which I have installed in my current instalation, after I can copy virtual composer.json to the original one, then composer will update the right version packages with the compatibility dependencies.

---

PUTTING symfony/symfony>3.0

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-bundle (locked at v1.2.0, required as >1.6) is satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 2
>       - The requested package twig/extensions (locked at v1.0.0, required as >1.0) is satisfiable by twig/extensions[v1.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 3
>       - The requested package symfony/assetic-bundle (locked at v2.3.0, required as >2.8) is satisfiable by symfony/assetic-bundle[v2.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 4
>       - The requested package symfony/monolog-bundle (locked at v2.3.0, required as >2.3) is satisfiable by symfony/monolog-bundle[v2.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 5
>       - The requested package incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (locked at v2.0.0, required as >2.0) is satisfiable by incenteev/composer-parameter-handler[v2.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 6
>       - symfony/symfony dev-master requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - symfony/symfony 4.0.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: How if you change all the version constraints from > to >=? Eg. "symfony/symfony": ">=3.0"

Comment: Same error. I update the head topic.

Comment: What version of composer do you have? Consider upgrading it to last version

Comment: I have the last one